# modify struct data in ISR STM32 microcontroller

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, microcontroller

I'm trying to estimate the pose of an dc motor with kalman filter in ISR on STM32F407 uC. My code does work well in main loop. Unfortunately it does not work in ISR. The execute duration is not longer then ISR time.

kalman_motor.c

```
/*  kalman_motor.c  */
#include "kalman_motor.h"

void pose_estimate(kalman_motor *k, float newPos){...}
```

kalman_motor.h

```
/*  kalman_motor.h  */

#ifndef KALMAN_MOTOR_H_
#define KALMAN_MOTOR_H_

typedef struct{
   float pos;
   float vel;

   float P1, P2, P3, P4;
   float Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4;
   float R;

   float dt;
}kalman_motor;

void pose_estimate(kalman_motor *k, float newPos);
#endif /* KALMAN_MOTOR_H_ */
```

I declare in main.c

```
kalman_motor motor_pose1;
```

and call

```
pose_estimate(&motor_pose1, measuredPos1);
```

in ISR.

i've tried with

```
volatile kalman_motor motor_pose1;
```

It still does not work. Compiler optimization level is on -Os.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**Edit**: It works well in ISR, if i don't use struct. There is no compiler warnings or errors. It does not work means it is in a state like getting caught. sry for my bad english

Comment: C or C++? You'll get a tighter focusing of experts if you pick one, and you could get hilariously bad answers from folk who code primarily in the other.

Comment: when you say it "does not work", what does that mean?

Comment: Change `kalman_motor *k` to `volatile kalman_motor *k` in the prototypes. Also keep `motor_pose1` volatile.

Comment: Are you sure that your ISR is working/called properly? Show you peripheral, timer and interrupt initialization.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo I've changed it to volatile as you suggest. It still does not work, like getting caught

Comment: @Flanker I'm sure, it works in ISR without using a **struct**.

Comment: "It still does not work" is vague.  Describe in detail how code does not work, what was seen, what was expected.    The ISR uses `motor_pose1`,  How does the rest of code use `motor_pose1`, if at all?

Comment: In which way it "doesn't work"? What does it mean that "it works without a struct"? As @chux points out, how is it used in the other code? Please try to prepare a minimized testcase that you can post.